# Is there a way to replace a string in a flowfile using a regex stored in a variable?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Nifi, and it looks like ReplaceText doesn't work properly.  I want to perform a text search and replace with these criteria:

1. I want to store a regex of my search string in a variable, not directly in a processor's property.
2. I want to store a regex of my replacement string in a variable, not directly in a processor's property.
3. I want to be able to only change the variables in the resulting template, so I can share it with other users via the Nifi registry.

I've tried using ExtractText to search for something, store that in an attribute, and then use the value of that attribute, but Nifi Expression Language scope is listed as unsupported for ExtractText user added properties.  ReplaceText works fine if you want to put the regex in the ReplaceText property, but I don't, since I'm sharing the template via the registry and any time someone changes that property for their own search text, there will be a new version in the registry.

Comment: The answer to your question - yes, it's possible. Look at doc: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/ Note the expression language support flag.

Comment: @daggett this is a documented bug in the Nifi Jira.  I'm looking for a workaround without using ReplaceText.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4417

Comment: i don't see how this issue affects your question.

Comment: @DumbNewbie which version of nifi are you using?

Comment: @Asankasanjaya Nifi 1.8.0

Comment: @daggett if you don't understand that something is broken and documented in the Nifi Jira,, I'm not sure how to simplify it any more for you